# Azure Redis Timeout Under load

Tags: redis, entity-framework-core, stackexchange.redis

I've implemented [this](https://github.com/VahidN/EFCoreSecondLevelCacheInterceptor) second level cache for EF Core exactly as described in the readme. Tonight I ran a load test on the system with about 500 virtual users and I am getting lots of timeouts like the following below:

**Azure Redis Premium 6 GB**

```
Message: Timeout performing GET (5000ms), next: GET 8664A5E9, inst: 51, qu: 0, qs: 101, aw: False, rs: ReadAsync, ws: Idle, in: 65536, serverEndpoint: xxxxx.redis.cache.windows.net:6380, mc: 1/1/0, mgr: 10 of 10 available, clientName: RD2818785C3C7F, IOCP: (Busy=6,Free=994,Min=4,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=63,Free=8128,Min=4,Max=8191), v: 2.1.58.34321 (Please take a look at this article for some common client-side issues that can cause timeouts: https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/Timeouts)
```

Relevant Startup Code

```
        const string providerName1 = "Redis1";
        services.AddEFSecondLevelCache(options =>
                options.UseEasyCachingCoreProvider(providerName1, CacheExpirationMode.Absolute, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5)).DisableLogging(true)
        );

        ConnectionMultiplexer.SetFeatureFlag("preventthreadtheft", true);

        services.AddEasyCaching(option => {
            option.UseRedis(config => {
                config.DBConfig.Configuration = AppConfig.RedisConnectionString;
                config.DBConfig.AllowAdmin = true;                    
            }, providerName1);
        });

    private DbContextOptionsBuilder<DBContext[![enter image description here][2]][2]> GetDBConfig(IContext context) {
        var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<DBContext>();
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(AppConfig.DatabaseConnection)
        .AddInterceptors(context.GetInstance<SecondLevelCacheInterceptor>())
        //.UseLoggerFactory()
        .EnableSensitiveDataLogging(true);
        return optionsBuilder;
    }
```

[image]